# Intellij open directory with ansible playbook scripts/yaml files as project

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to open a directory as a project in Intellij. The directory contains automation/ansible scripts (yaml/sh/etc) files. Tried to search for solution but with no result. How can I do this in IntelliJ?

Comment: Try creating a new module of Static Web type and add a content root for this directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS, do

```
$ cd /path/to/the/project/root/directory
$ open -a 'IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2' &
```

Project will be automatically created.

Answer (score -1):

The following steps works for me. I am using Ultimate 2018.2 with `YAML/Ansible support` plugin installed.

1. `File>New>Project from Existing Sources` or if adding as a module in existing project(s) `File>New>Module from Existing Sources`, then select the folder that contains the scripts.
2. In next window, select the `Create project from existing sources` option. The click `Next` in succeeding windows then `Finish`.